# Syntax to include/reference a .PHP file within a .JS file

Tags: javascript, php, include

I am moving some form validation from a `PHP` file to a `JS` file. One portion of the validation is captcha validation which includes a reference to an external PHP file. Is it possible to reference an external PHP file in a JS file (with a modified version of the above syntax)? I tried several ways but seem to be coming up short. If it is possible, can someone point me in the right direction on the general syntax? Ideally I would want to do all my validation in the same file if it's not too much legwork.

Comment: you can include this file in PHP file where you have included JS file

Comment: loadurl('file_name.php');

Comment: If you move validation to JS it will be executed client side, and therefore is no longer really a client validation. You are now asking the client, "Are you legit?". What would it prove if it answered *Yes!* ?

Comment: Let me give the names of the files so I can better understand you. That code snippit is currently in Submit.php however I would like to move it to Validate.js

Comment: refer this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/247081-javascript-to-loadruncall-php-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your .js file with the ending .php, then you can include normal PHP-Code in it, which gets parsed by the server. If you're using Apache you can also add the following to the .htaccess to treat every .js file as PHP file and keep the .js file extension:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
```

Anyway, don't forget to add this **on top** of the JS-File so the client recognizes it as JS-File (but it's still a PHP file for the server):

```
<?php
    header(Content-Type: text/javascript);
?>
```

Example for the file:

```
<?php
    header(Content-Type: text/javascript);
?>

function abc () {
    // some JS-Code
}

<?php
    include 'validate.php'; /* including PHP file, but it has to output valid JS-Code! */
?>

// Back to JS
function def () {
    // more JS-Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If having extension ".js", the we cannot use php syntax on ".js" file.
But if you are using javascript on ".php" file, then as you knows that we can use the php syntax on javascript.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are saying that there is no way to reference/include "Captcha.php" from within "Validate.js"?

Comment: Upon further reading, it seems that validation is generally recommended in both the .js file as a courtesy to visitors (where possible obviously) and also in the .php file in case javascript is disabled and for more secure validation. So instead of moving validation from the .php file to the .js file, I should ideally have it in BOTH places (with the exception of the captcha validation which will only be done in the .php file as it was probably meant to be by design).